# Google Closure Compiler returning in different encoding?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, encoding, character-encoding, google-closure-compiler

Google Closure Compiler returns the following code:

```
{"compiledCode":"vaporize\u003dfunction(){var a\u003d12+Math.random()*10;a\u003e9\u0026\u0026console.log(\"wow, k is bigger than j\");return 9+3*a};compilation_level\u003dADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS;vaporize\u003dfunction(){var a\u003d12+Math.random()*10;a\u003e9\u0026\u0026console.log(\"wow, k is bigger than j\");return 9+3*a};"}
```

It replaced (I think) equal signs with \u003d and some other stuff. What's wrong ?

My post variables are:
'compilation_level' :

```
'ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS',  
'output_format': 'json',
'warning_level' : 'QUIET',
'output_info' : 'compiled_code',
'js_code' : code
```

Edit1: Only if I set 'output_format' : 'text' the encoding comes out right.

Answer (score 1):

> It replaced (I think) equal signs with \u003d and some other stuff. What's wrong ?

Nothing. `"\u003d"` is a valid JavaScript (or, here, JSON) representation of a string containing an equals character; it is completely equivalent to `"="`.

What are you doing with the output to make it matter? If you don't want JSON output, you should indeed ask for raw ‘text’.

Comment: Well, the raw text javascript function runs well but that thing that came out encoded or not in a different way gives the following error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: That's what Chrome will give you in various circumstances like a string literal with a newline in it. It doesn't appear for me given your example string.

Comment: Well, I have: > eval('k \u003d 3') ; > k == 3 ; and it yields true, but > k \u003d 4
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: Yes, `\u003D` is an escape in a string literal; you can't have it outside a string literal. But you wouldn't take part of a JSON string and `eval` it, you have to `JSON.parse` or `eval` the whole thing and extract the data you need from the result.